# Mongodb Query to filter documents based on the length of a field value

Tags: mongodb-query, aws-documentdb

I am writing a AWS lambda code in python. My database is AWS DocumentDB. And I use pymongo.

This code snippet works fine
`query = {"media_id": {"$exists": True}} collection.find(query)`

But it returns a lot of records, so I want to fetch the records where the length of media_id field is less than 3.

For that I tried this query `query = { "media_id": {"$exists": True}, "$expr: {"$lt": [{"$strLenCP": "$media_id"}, 3]},}`, but I get

> Feature not supported Error

because $expr is not supported in DocumentDB.
I am looking for the query which works in DocumentDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution might seems a bit tedious, but all the operations inside should be supported according to the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html)

Use an aggregation to project an auxiliary field to store the length of `media_id` then match on your criteria.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      length: {
        "$strLenCP": "$media_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      media_id: {
        $exists: true
      },
      length: {
        $gte: 3
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      length: false
    }
  }
])
```